# PHP 7.3 returning strange results using PDO SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

When I run the query below under different versions of PHP/PDO_SQLSRV, I get a different result. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, like a binary encoding setting?

```
$hex = '0x44';

$sSQL = "
DECLARE @hex nvarchar(6) = :hex
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(2), @hex, 1) myTest
";

$stmt = $this->rms->prepare($sSQL);
$stmt->bindParam(':hex',$hex);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
```

Result from PHP 7.0.8 + php_pdo_sqlsrv 4.1.8819:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [myTest] => 44
        )

)
```

Result from PHP 7.3.4 + php_pdo_sqlsrv 5.6.1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [myTest] => D
        )

)
```

Result from SQL Server 2008 R2:

[image: Result from SQL Server 2008 R2]

Comment: Probably an issue with the driver: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/270 and https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/10854. I get the same result (`'D'`) with `PHP 7.1.12` and `pdo-sqlsrv 4.3.0+9904`.

Comment: Yeah I think so! We've done more testing/reading and it looks like one of those situations where the old driver was 'doing it wrong'. Unfortunately our PHP scripts preferred the wrong way! Looking at converting now, will post what we did if it works.